# Viewing GeoPandas Dataframe in VScode or PyCharm like Pandas Dataframes

Tags: geopandas, pandas, pycharm, spyder, visual-studio-code

I'm not sure if this is a missing feature or something that I couldn't figure out so I wanted to get some help; I started learning geopandas library, now I'm following some tutorials I realized that neither pycharm nor vscode have the ability to show geopandas dataframes like they do in pandas dataframes. I have checked the same code in Spyder that comes bundled with Anaconda distribution and I have the ability to see and inspect geopandas dataframes just like pandas dataframes.

Here is what I see on VSCODE same is true for PyCharm as well, if I double click on pandas dataframe it shows me the entire dataframe, if I double click on geopandas dataframe nothing happens.
[image: this is pandas dataframe on VSCODE]

This is the same exact code in Spyder, no matter which dataframe I double click, it shows me the content.

[image: This is geopandas and pandas dataframes on Spyder]

Am I missing anything or this is not possible using PyCharm or VS Code?